# Subtrack values of a column between 2 datasets and keep track of the current value for following lines

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a problem I have struggled on for a few days now... I have 2 dataframes, one containing orders, the other containing cancellations. Basically, let's keep it simple, their schema is [unique_id_line, reference, qty, date]. I need to cancel every quantity contained in cancellations via their reference. In the end I must only keep my order dataframe without the lines that have been cancelled, and if an order is partially cancelled, its quantity must be right. Determining which order a cancellation can cancel is made via the "reference" field.

Some rules apply:

- A cancellation will cancel its quantity first on the order that has the same reference and the nearest date on same day or before
- If the cancelled quantity is too much for an order, it must decrease the value of the next order, descending by date
- we start with the newest cancellation

Some examples to better understand the problem:

### Example 1

**orders:**

```
[
    [id1, ref1, 5, 10/04/2023], 
    [id2, ref1, 10, 20/04/2023], 
    [id3, ref1, 2, 30/04/2023], 
    [id6, ref2, 2, 01/04/2023]
]
```

**cancellations:**

```
[
    [id4, ref1, 12, 25/04/2023], 
    [id5, ref1, 2, 30/04/2023]
]
```

**expected result:**

```
[
    [id1, ref1, 3, 10/04/2023], 
    [id6, ref2, 2, 01/04/2023]
]
```

**explanation:**

id5 (newest cancellation because 30 > 25) cancels entirely id3, then id4 cancels the 10 parts of id2 + 2 parts of id1. id6 is not modified because there are no cancellations on ref2

### Example 2

Right now I have some working code based on window and lag, but it's quite ugly and doesn't work with another case, when several cancellations are linked to several orders, like below:

**orders:**

```
[
    [id1, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023],
    [id2, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023],
    [id5, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023]
]
```

**cancellations:**

```
[
    [id3, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023],
    [id4, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023],
    [id6, ref1, 13, 30/04/2023]
]
```

**expected result:**

```
[
    [id5, ref1, 29, 10/04/2023]
]
```

**explanation:**

id6 is the newest cancellation, cancels 13 parts on id1 (order between orders there doesn't matter so we take the first one), 29 parts left on id1
id4 cancels the 29 left parts of id1 + 13 other parts on id2
id3 cancels the 29 left parts of id2 + 13 other parts on id5, id5 has 29 parts left

### Example 3

Right now I have some working code based on window and lag, but it's quite ugly and doesn't work with another case, when several cancellations are linked to several orders, like below:

**orders:**

```
[
    [id1, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023],
    [id2, ref1, 42, 11/04/2023],
    [id5, ref1, 42, 12/04/2023]
]
```

**cancellations:**

```
[
    [id3, ref1, 43, 15/04/2023]
]
```

**expected result:**

```
[
    [id1, ref1, 42, 10/04/2023],
    [id2, ref1, 41, 11/04/2023],
]
```

**explanation:**

id3 cancels all 42 parts on id5 (the newest one), and 1 part on id2

---

I think there might be a simpler solution but struggle to find it... The real difficulty I have is to keep track of the left quantity a cancellation can still cancel, as a lag can't reuse a previous computed line and we can't loop in pyspark :/

Any help or at least indication of a good lead would be so helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

With pandas the following function gives the expected result for both examples:

```
def get_aggregated_orders(orders, cancellations):
    orders_total = orders.groupby(['reference']).agg({'unique_id_line': 'min', 'qty': 'sum', 'date': 'min'})
    orders_total = orders.groupby(['reference']).agg({'unique_id_line': 'min', 'qty': 'sum', 'date': 'min'}).reset_index()

    cancellations_total = cancellations.groupby('reference').agg({'qty': 'sum'}).reset_index()
    cancellations_total = cancellations_total.rename(columns={'qty':'qty_to_subtract'})

    result = orders_total.merge(cancellations_total, on='reference', how='left')
    result = result.fillna(value={'qty_to_subtract':0})
    result['qty'] = result['qty']-result['qty_to_subtract']

    return result[['unique_id_line', 'reference', 'qty', 'date']]
```

For PySpark I cannot test it at the moment, but it should look something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def get_aggregated_orders(orders, cancellations):
    orders_total = orders.groupBy('reference')\
        .agg(min('unique_id_line').alias('unique_id_line'), \
             sum('qty').alias('qty'), \
             min('date').alias('date') )
    
    cancellations_total = cancellations.groupBy('reference')\
        .agg(sum('qty'))\
        .withColumnRenamed('qty', 'qty_to_subtract')
    
    result = orders_total.join(cancellations_total, on='reference', how='left')\
        .fillna({'qty_to_subtract': 0})\
        .withColumn('qty', F.col('qty') - F.col('qty_to_subtract'))\
        .select('unique_id_line', 'reference', 'qty', 'date')
    
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is an interesting approach, way more clean than I am using, but it doesn't keep the right id for the second example. I added a third example which will show more easily how your solution doesn't work. Actually I have a lot more columns than on these examples, I tried to keep it the simpler I could but for this reason keeping the right id is essential :/